# Can't use OData with SQL Server 2016 (DTExec 13)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

I've build a simple package that extract data from an OData source.

It work with DTExec 12 (SQL Server 2014) but when I deploy to an SQL Server 2016 (DTExec 13) I got a weird error in french :

> La connexion « Connexion » est introuvable. Vérifier que le gestionnaire de connexions renferme une connexion de ce nom.

Lousy translate in English it mean :

> The connection "connexion" is not found. Check if the connections managers has a connection with this name.

I have no connection named connexion in my package.

Do you have any ideas how I could investigate this error ? How can I look at the available connections in the connection managers ?

I feel like there is no OData connector installed for SQL Server 2016 but there is an old one that was installed with SQL Server 2014 because DTExec 12 work on the same server with the same package.

Comment: is there any news ? i have the same error i can't call the Odata from ssis package there is no connexion

Comment: @ARAZI, sorry, I never found an answer. I had to format the server and start over.

Comment: also i have juste installed the 2014 extention and it works but not the  2016